# how can you apply a filter on a UIImage as if it is sprayed on a brick wall?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-image, cifilter

I want to blend an image with a background image.
As if it is sprayed on a wall.
How can i obtain a realistic blend.

I have tried alpha but not giving good results.

I am quit new in this CoreImage stuff.
Please help.

Something similiar to this.
http://designshack.net/wp-content/uploads/texturetricks-14.jpg

i googled some but no luck.
I even do not know what i am looking for exactly.
Not sure how to google it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to blend two images together.

```
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"];

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

// Use existing opacity as is
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
// Apply supplied opacity
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of works. I found a [smiley face image](http://clipartion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/white-smiley-face-on-black-background-smiley-faces-pinterest.jpg) - white on black - and a [brick background](https://www.colourbox.com/preview/1639830-old-brick-wall-background.jpg).

The first job is to create `CIImage` versions of the pair. I pass the smiley face through a `CIMaskToAlpha` filter to make the black transparent:

```
let brick = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "brick.jpg")!)!

let smiley = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "smiley.jpg")!)!
    .imageByApplyingFilter("CIMaskToAlpha", withInputParameters: nil)
```

Then composite the pair together with `CISubtractBlendMode`:

```
let composite = brick
    .imageByApplyingFilter("CISubtractBlendMode",
        withInputParameters: [kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: smiley])
```

The final result is almost there:

[image]

The subtract blend will only really work with white artwork.

Here's another approach: using `CISoftLightBlendMode` for the blend, bumping up the gamma to brighten the effect and then compositing that over the original brickwork using the smiley as a mask:

```
let composite = smiley
    .imageByApplyingFilter("CISoftLightBlendMode",
        withInputParameters: [kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: brick])
    .imageByApplyingFilter("CIGammaAdjust",
        withInputParameters: ["inputPower": 0.5])
    .imageByApplyingFilter("CIBlendWithMask",
        withInputParameters: [kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: brick, kCIInputMaskImageKey: smiley])
```

Which gives:

[image]

This approach is nice because you can control the paint whiteness with the gamma power.

Simon

Comment: Will they only work for white ? What can we do for colored smiley ?